# White lines appearing in 3D extruded text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, svg, 3d, responsive-design

**I just began learning illustrator so please excuse my ignorance.**

I created this design in illustrator:[image]

My question pertains to the cause and fix of the white lines appearing on the text:
[image]

I exported the image for screens in the formats PDF, SVG, and PDF.
The white lines appear only in the SVG and PDF versions when opened in browsers (chrome, firefox, edge) and in Adobe Acrobat. They appear only slightly when pasted into a Photoshop document.

*The PNG version does not contain these errors.*

I've tried messing with the format settings in the export menu for the SVG and PDF versions but the lines persist no matter what.

My understanding is that this is only an issue with the way these images are rendered on screen as the lines are not present when I tried printing the image.

Is there any way I can get rid of the lines so I can use the SVG version for a responsive website? I want to avoid having to use a PNG as much as possible.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's annoying. Hard to tell what your problem is without the .ai file.
Have you made sure the shapes making up the shadows are totally clean and merged? Did you make the shadows using a fancy tool or did you make them manually? A lot of Illustrator's effects has small inaccuracies and faults and they don't always translate well to svg.

Comment: I just began using Illustrator a couple of days ago, so i'm still very new to all of the tools and the workflow. 
I made the text using the 3D extrude and Bevel tool. 
After that I duplicated the layer and placed one behind the saw blade to get the cutting effect. I've read elsewhere that doing the shading manually can help to simplify the design and minimize errors. I will have to learn how to do it manually if there's no fix for what I already have. 

Here is a dropbox lint to the ai file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9qv38uhxmqwywc/awwlogo.ai?dl=0

Comment: @MadsWolff no its not this is known as a conflation error. Its a bug of sorts, your shapes must overlap or it will pop up in most vector graphics renderers. See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg/65060#65060

Comment: Cody merge all objects to one then paste the colored ones on top.

Comment: Try looking at your artwork in wireframe (ctrl+y). You can see how the automatic effect has a lot of "noise". It is made up of tiny bits - somewhere in there lies the problem. You will have to live with it or recreate the design in a more "manual" way. @joojaa. Might work! I was just advocating for drawing things yourself to make sure everything is just right.

Comment: @MadsWolff if you merge the shapes the effect will mostly go away. But really, its a bug in the way renderers are implemented in most cases.

Comment: @joojaa I copied everything, flattened the artwork, and pasted it on top in a new layer and it helped tremendously. Repeated it once more and all of the lines are gone. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yeh Illustrator's 3D does this. The reason for the white lines is basically the same issue described in [Objects do not align precisely in Illustrator CC](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/67300/52050) and [Image looks embossed when converted to SVG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65058/52050) and [Space between 2 paths in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/47342/52050) and the reason for [Is there a reason Hillary Clinton's logo has hidden notches?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73601/52050) ...and countless other previous Q&As.

The easiest solution:

1. Duplicate the shapes
2. Merge them in to a single shape using Pathfinder
3. Set them to an appropriate color
4. Place them behind the original

Or you could give the shapes a stroke, or use the Offset Path command (or effect), or overlap the shapes in some other way. You basically either need to overlap the shapes or place them on a background of a better color.

Comment: Great! I duplicated the shapes and the lines are gone! Thanks for the help!