# Vector Font Problem / How To Save

Tags: fonts, vector, inkscape, text, save

I'm using Inkscape to create a logo, where I need one font on top of the other. The problem is that I get a line around the bottom font, like:

[image]

When I zoom right in the red lower text isn't visible, so I'm guessing this is a pixel error as opposed to an actual error, but when I try to save it as a JPG, I still get the red line around it.

I'm using the logo/text on a professional poster and would obviously like to make sure that it saves without this red line/lower color showing through, how do I acheive this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're deleting your questions then asking them again? Especially after people have requested more information/clarifications you should really [edit] you question to make changes rather than deleting.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do anyway... why do you need to layer the type? Without that red showing through surely it looks exactly the same as it not being layered at all?

Comment: No Cai, this is a Completely different question To my other question!!! As you would know if you read it?

Comment: I'm layering because I want to edit the background text, but before I do that I need to get rid of this outer glow!!!

Comment: @Cai Refer to my latest question (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85007/inkscape-filters-edit-tool-box) for an update of what I'm trying to do, this question is supposed to be deleted for a reason!

Comment: That question is different yes, but the other two you deleted are *exactly* the same question, I don't know why you'd argue otherwise. I can answer this question but if you don't want the answer anymore and you're just going to delete it then there is is no point

Comment: If someone can give me some actual feedback without wanting me to edit the ORIGINAL post so much that I feel it has to be deleted then no I won't delete it, and will give it a tick/up vote, but it seems

Comment: ... people want to comment without having the first clue about a possible solution. If you can answer then that would be great. However, my new question is just as in need of an answer as well as this one

Comment: That's exactly what comments are for, to ask for clarifications and more information... There was nothing wrong with your original question. I've answered this because it's a known issue but I don't use Inkscape to give you any more specifics on your other question. Keep in mind this site is pretty quite on weekends so you may need to be patient waiting for answers!

Comment: I was talking about my previous post that had to be deleted. To be honest I'm more interested in getting me NEW post answered, which is why I asked it and deleted my previous ones

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you see the bottom layer is essentially a rendering artefact and is basically the same issue described in [Objects do not align precisely in Illustrator CC](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/67300/52050) and [Image looks embossed when converted to SVG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65058/52050) and [Space between 2 paths in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/47342/52050) ...and countless other previous Q&As. Read through those to get a better idea of what is happening.

To prevent the bottom layer showing you just need to offset the path a small amount. I don't use Inkscape — but in Illustrator I would use the Offset Path function. A quick search shows that [Inkscape has a similar function](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html#Paths-Offsets).