# Illustrator: Removing white borders from boxes after Create Object Map

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, images, bitmap

I'm trying to create an 8bit cave image in Illustrator for a fun little 404 page but am having trouble on export. The file in Illustrator looks like this screenshot:

[image: cave]

However, when I export the image as a png, I see white boxes around each pixel of the image:[image]

I exported the image as svg as well, and the white boxes also appear there. It seems like that's because each of the `rect` elements has a slight bit of space between them:

```
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 692 466">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1 {
            fill: #ffebb2;
          }

          .cls-2 {
            fill: #ebd798;
          }

          .cls-3 {
            fill: #cbb076;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <title>cave</title>
      <g>
        <rect class="cls-1" x="681.97" y="455.87" width="10.03" height="10.13"/>
        <rect class="cls-2" x="671.94" y="455.87" width="10.03" height="10.13"/>
        <rect class="cls-2" x="661.91" y="455.87" width="10.03" height="10.13"/>
        <rect class="cls-2" x="651.88" y="455.87" width="10.03" height="10.13"/>
        <rect class="cls-3" x="641.86" y="455.87" width="10.03" height="10.13"/>
        {...MORE SVG...}
```

I believe I could fix this problem with some scripting by giving each rect element a nice integer height and width and then 'snapping' each of those rects to a perfectly round position on the x, y axis. I would much prefer to fix the problem in Illustrator however, as I want to get better at it.

Does anyone know how I can remove the white boxes that surround each rect element in the exported svg? I tried `Object -> Make Pixel Perfect` but that made even larger white boxes around the exported rects. Any help others can provide would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this for a moment, I realized those white boxes could be the result of the `stroke` style on the `rect` elements. I opened up my svg and added `rect {stroke:red};` to the inline styles and sure enough I saw the whole grid light up:

```
<svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewbox="0 0 692 466" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
    <style>
    rect {
      stroke: red;
    }

    .cls-1 {
        fill: #ffebb2;
      }
```

[image]

This told me that the stroke styles were creating that grid effect. From there I realized that if I set the stroke attribute of each element to its fill color, the grid would go away, and sure enough it did:

```
<svg data-name="Cave" id="cave" viewbox="0 0 692 466" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
    <style>
     .cls-1 {
        fill: #ffebb2;
        stroke: #ffebb2;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #ebd798;
        stroke: #ebd798;
      }
```

Here's the svg in Chrome:[image]

I'd still like to know how to do this in Illustrator, but am happy to have worked it out.

Comment: The problem isn't the stroke, it's actually a rendering artefact (see e.g. [Space between 2 paths in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/47342/52050) and [Objects do not align precisely in Illustrator CC](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/67300/52050) and [Image looks embossed when converted to SVG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65058/52050) and lots of other previous questions) ...Setting a stroke the same color as your fill is a perfectly good fix though :)

Comment: Thanks @Cai, how would one fix this problem in Illustrator so that the exported result would not have the white boxes in the svgs?

Answer (score 0):

Try aligning the vector boxes to pixel grid by selecting the entire thing is finding the "align to pixel grid" option. It may be the solution, or it may not.

Answer (score 0):

I can show two ways to do it.
These are described in the picture below.

[image]